# How to store the first line of text file in JAVA LIST

Tags: java

I don't know what going wrong with my code it supposed to display the first line of my text file when I use `list.get(0)` but I always get the 2nd line !!

```
String everything;
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("lol/new.txt"))) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = br.readLine();

    while (line != null) {
        sb.append(line);
        sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
        line = br.readLine();
        list.add(line);
    }

    everything = sb.toString(); // maybe I'll need this :D 
}
```

FILE.TXT

```
10 10
5 5 N
DADADADAA
```

when I do a simple `System.out.println(list.get(0));` I get `5 5 N` instead of `10 10` what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: You're double reading the file `String line = br.readLine();`, followed by `line = br.readLine();`, use `while ((line = br.readLine) != null) {...` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    String everything;
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("lol/new.txt"))) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = br.readLine(); // Read first line

        while (line != null) {
            sb.append(line);
            sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
            list.add(line); // Line order has changed!
            line = br.readLine(); // Read next line
        }
        everything = sb.toString(); // maybe I'll need this :D 

    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by `Line Number Changed`... ArrayList saves insertion order so that's not an issue

Comment: @Manoj order has changed. Now, first appending to list then read next line

Comment: You should point out his mistake of overwriting `line` variable by reading second line from text file. Ok As I see... now you have done it. great !!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that outside of the `while` loop you already pull up the first line and inside the `while` loop's iteration, you never use that first line you pulled.

Try pulling the next line at the end of your `while` loop, thus using the `line` pulled from before the while loop as well:

```
while (line != null) {
    sb.append(line);
    sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
    list.add(line);
    line = br.readLine();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to my comments on the code

```
    String everything;
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("lol/new.txt"))) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = br.readLine();

        while (line != null) {
            sb.append(line);
            sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
            //up to this point variable line has the line number 1
            //first line is overwritten with line number 2
            line = br.readLine();
            //when you add the line to your ArrayList, line variable contains the second line
            list.add(line);
        }
        everything = sb.toString();

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the comments in the code.

```
    String everything;
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("lol/new.txt"))) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = br.readLine(); // You read first line of file
                                     // which is discarded.

        while (line != null) {
            sb.append(line);
            sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
            line = br.readLine(); // You read second, and the rest of lines of file.
                                  // First line is discarded here.
            list.add(line);       // Add to list.
        }
        everything = sb.toString(); // maybe I'll need this :D 

    }
```